# Days required to catch fishes in a pond

Tags: probability-distributions

A pond holds 4 fish. Each day a fisherman goes fishing and his probability of catching **K = 0,1,2,3,4** fish that day follows a binomial PDF with *p = 1/2*.How many days should he plan on fishing so that the probability of his catching all 4 fish exceeds 0.9?

Can someone just give a hint on how to start thinking to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ is a an iid sequence of random variables with binomial distribution with parameters $4$ and $0.5$ then $X_1+\cdots+X_k$ has binomial distribution with parameters $4k$ and $0.5$.

To be found here is the smallest $k$ that satisfies: $$P(X_1+\cdots+X_k\geq4)>0.9$$